# Slick 3.1.1 deduplication errors with sbt-assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, slick, hikaricp, sbt-assembly

I'm using Slick 3.1.1 in a Scala project. My `build.sbt libraryDependencies` contains this:

```
"com.typesafe.slick"  %% "slick"           % "3.1.1",
"com.typesafe.slick"  %% "slick-hikaricp"  % "3.1.1",    
"com.zaxxer"          % "HikariCP"         % "2.4.3",
"mysql"               % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38",
```

Everything works. However, when I try to deploy with `sbt-assembly` I get errors like this:

```
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/thunderkid/.ivy2/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP-java6/bundles/HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.class
[error] /home/thunderkid/.ivy2/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/bundles/HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.class
```

How do I fix these?

Previously I was using Slick 3.0, which doesn't need `slick-hikaricp`, and it worked fine. I tried deleting `.ivy2/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP-java6`, but that doesn't work - it's just recreated. My `mergeStrategy` is

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
    {
        case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "ArgumentsProcessor.class" => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "MatchersBinder.class" => MergeStrategy.first
        case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
        case "unwanted.txt"     => MergeStrategy.discard
        case x => old(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible that the slick-hikaricp dependency is pulling in the HikariCP-java6 dependency.  You can either remove the explicit dependency on HikariCP, or override the HikariCP-java6 dependency.  See [this page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html) about how to force/override dependencies.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks. I've shown my working line in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @brettw's advice in his comment above, I got it to work by adding an `exclude` command into `build.sbt` as follows:

```
"com.typesafe.slick"  %% "slick-hikaricp"  % "3.1.1"   exclude("com.zaxxer", "HikariCP-java6"),
```

Comment: I think you should instead remove the line `"com.zaxxer"          % "HikariCP"         % "2.4.3",` altogether. HikariCP is already a hard dependency of `slick-hikaricp`